# Is it possible to divide work between cores?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have this simple (dummy) code  : *(heavy computed : 30 sec in my machine)*

```
BigInteger number = BigInteger.Pow(Int64.MaxValue, 300000);
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Plinq will do the job division automatically . (divide work to threads). but it will work on Ienumerable (followed by AsParallel)

Here I don't have Ienumerable object. I just have 1 command.

How can I divide *my command* among the available cores  ?

currently (as you can see) only 1 core is doing the hard work :

[image]

## Edit :

Putting it under Task will not divide it among all cores :

```
Task<BigInteger> t=Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>BigInteger.Pow(Int64.MaxValue, 300000));

Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't worked with `BigInteger`, but I don't see anything in the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that would lend me to think that the method can be distributed to multiple threads. It _appears_ as though the method is written as a single, synchronous process which would be impossible to break into multiple threads short of re-implementing it yourself.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair It is amazing that today , 2013 , We can't divide command's work and use our machine computing power. Im talking about commands like in my sample)

Comment: Not unless the _actual work_ is _designed_ to be distributed to multiple, generally independent, tasks. Especially if the work is dependent on the results of the previously executed instructions, _in order_, then it's impossible to just "flip a switch" and have all your cores work on it.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair IMHO linq , when built , was not designed to work on future plinq....and still , plinq does divide to threads , and aggregate data - by ITSELF !

Comment: Depends on the usage. If you're calling something like `Aggregate`, then that _can_ be divided into separate distinct tasks because it is _assumed_ that it can enumerate/sum the entities separately. It's generally _easy_ to multithread a loop. But in this case you aren't; all you have is a _single method_ (`BigInteger.Pow`) which is a _black box_ to all outside code. It _could_ be implemented in a threaded fashion, it _could_ be using file system resources, it _could_ be just a single `while` loop. The point is, the calling code _doesn't know_ and has _no mechanism_ to break up its work.

Comment: Also, just to note: PLINQ isn't guaranteed to be thread-safe. There's _nothing_ that guarantees that the LINQ query itself will execute properly in a threaded context. _You_, the developer, still has to make sure that the query/usage of PLINQ is thread-safe. All PLINQ does is give you some _convenience_ with parallelizing your queries. It's a _tool_ that must be used _correctly_ and when it is _warranted._

Comment: @ChrisSinclair correct.  that's why we should use ThreadLocal<> or special aggregate methods.(for accumulating data among different threads)(regarding your last comment)

Comment: There is no way to magically parallelize arbitrary code. We won't get that pre-singularity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't worked with `BigInteger`, but I don't see anything in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.numerics.biginteger.pow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that would lend me to think that the method can be distributed to multiple threads. It appears as though the method is written as a single, synchronous process which would be impossible to break into multiple threads short of re-implementing it yourself.

EDIT: If you look at the [Mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Numerics/System.Numerics/BigInteger.cs), or another [open source implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2728/C-BigInteger-Class), you may be able to rewrite their `Pow` methods to be muiti-threaded.

```
public static BigInteger Pow (BigInteger value, int exponent)
{
    if (exponent < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("exponent", "exp must be >= 0");
    if (exponent == 0)
        return One;
    if (exponent == 1)
        return value;

    BigInteger result = One;
    while (exponent != 0) 
    {
        if ((exponent & 1) != 0)
            result = result * value;
        if (exponent == 1)
            break;

        value = value * value;
        exponent >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Though looking at its process and its build-up/dependency on the previous loop (it alters/updates `exponent`, `value`, and `result`) it may be <s>difficult</s> non-trivial to write a new routine altogether that can break this work up and distribute it to multiple threads.

Comment: In principle you can execute the squaring and the multiplication in parallel. Once the numbers are large enough, one could also parallelize the multiplication internally.

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you please show 1 line of  pseudo code of how the multiplication will look like ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir With schoolbook multiplication you could simply split one of the factor in `n` parts, multiply separately, and in the end add them up again. But for large factors schoolbook multiplication will be much slower than advanced multiplication techniques (much bigger difference than the gain through parallelism). Advanced techniques are pretty complex, (involved fourier transform etc.). Certainly not something done with 1 line of pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

@royi,

If you keep some logic along with TaskParallelLibrary you can achieve the task. Bydefault I don't think .Net big integer supports parallelism. Try the below

```
    pubilic BigInteger ParallelBigPow(Int64 value, int expo)
    {
        int procCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        BigInteger result = 1;
        Parallel.For(0, procCount, (index) => result = result * BigInteger.Pow(value, expo / procCount));
        return result;
    }
```

Now this works perfectly if your exponent is divisible by the procCount. You need to tweak the logic little to work with any exponent :-) If you face any difficult, let me know.

Comment: I think theres a problem with this solution.. result variable can be concurently accessed and modified by multiple threads and that could cause wrong results. There should be lock around statement that changes result variable. but if you do that the calculation could be slower than the single thread one is.

Comment: @jure ,I agree that we need to put the lock.Thats why I told my solution is to complete. But I don't think the lock overhead will make the time equal to the NO THREAD scenario because the POWs happens in multiple thread and multiplication is lock based..

Comment: only way to know for sure is to try and test performance. Here's my thinking. OP is trying to calculate Pow(Int64.MaxValue,300000).In your proposed solution for let’s say ProcCount=8, you would have final 8 multiplications of some huge numbers. That multiplications can't be done in parallel because next one depends on the result from the previous. So you need lock to assure that. And i believe that multiplication which produces final result will take more time then all operations before that. So i think the one thread solution would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question and realize it is an old one.

I believe TPL (parallel.for/foreach) relies on the OS to distribute work to threads on various cores, so you would not be able to do this explicitly suing the boiler-plate, standard approaches. I do not think TPL was designed for that. But there may be a way to accomplish this by assigning a Task or delegate method to a particular processor that a thread should run on by using the ProcessThread.ProcessorAffinity property.

Answer (score -1):

if it is acceptable, you could delegate your work to a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) process, the framework will automatically dispatch the workload onto your 8 cores.

This object also permit you to start the process async (via the [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h01xszh2.aspx))

It is very easy to use "multicore" threads through BW.

Comment: see my edit.........Task will put the Task **itself** in another core . it will not divide the work into chunks or partitions like plinq does

Answer (score -2):

That seem to work fine on Win 8 and .Net 4.0.  The "arrow" Shows where I started Debugging.  The load is not symetric, but all cores are being used.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger number = BigInteger.Pow(Int64.MaxValue, 300000);
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The same code on mine does not; it never peaks above 12.5% (8 core machine). It's _plausible_ that the runtime might transfer the work from one logical processor to the next, but at any given time only a single process can work on it at once.

Comment: Does one or more of your cores max out doing while(true){};?  As you can see all my cores are used.